# ActiveMQ Artemis Persisted Message Size Very Large

Tags: persistence, activemq-artemis

I am using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.11.0 with the native, file-based persistence configuration. Most of the content of my messages is around 5K characters.  However, the "Persistent Size" of the message is often 7 to 10 times larger than that.

The message data is a JSON string of various sizes. The "Persistent Size" value that I'm seeing comes from the queue browsing feature of the ActiveMQ Artemis web console. For example, a message with a display body character count of 4553 characters has a persistent size of 26,930 bytes. The persisted record is 6 times larger than the message itself.

There are headers in the message, but not enough I think to account for the difference in message and persisted record size.

Can anyone please tell me why this is and whether or not I can do something to reduce the persisted size of messages?

Here's a related screenshot of the web console:

[image: ActiveMQ Artemis Queue Display]

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example including the code you used to send the message, the message data itself, how you measured the size on disk, etc.?

Comment: The message data is a JSON string of various sizes.  The "Persistent Size" value that I'm using comes from the GUI message queue browse list.  

For example, a message with a display body character count of 4553 characters has a persistent size of 26,930 bytes.  The persisted record is 6 times larger than the message itself.

We're using Artemis 2.11.0, which I think has a bug in the time display on the GUI, so I don't know if that would affect the displayed size.

I can't provide an example as the data is proprietary.  It's a "wrapped" JSON mostly.

Comment: Yes, there are headers in the message, but not enough to account for the difference in message and persisted record size.

Comment: What is "display body character count"? Is that also something you see on the Artemis Web Console?

Comment: If you go to the Artemis console, select "Queues", then click on the message count on the right-hand column, you will be taken to a screen where you will see a list (typically up to 100) of messages in the queue.  Click on one of the messages and an "overlay" will pop up showing the message contents.  Part of that display is a count of the number of characters in the message itself.